# Columns not updating in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have some columns in my table that are not updating.  I have checked everything many times and everything is spelled correctly and should be working.

I have the following in my view:

```
@section('content')
```

```
  {{ csrf_field() }}


  <h1 class='py-3'>List of Providers</h1>


  <div class='form-group'>
    <textarea  name='survey_providers_list' type='' rows='10' class='form-control' id='' value = '{{ old('survey_providers_list') }}'></textarea>
    <div>{{ $errors->first('survey_providers_list') }}</div>
  </div>

  <h1 class='py-3'>Comments & Questions</h1>

  <p>Pleasee let us know any comments or questions you may have about our plan.</p>

  <div class='form-group'>
    <textarea  name='comments' type='' rows='10' class='form-control' id='' value = '{{ old('comments') }}'></textarea>
    <div>{{ $errors->first('comments') }}</div>
  </div>

  <h1 class='py-3'>Individual Health Insurance</h1>

  <p>If you do not want to join our plan and would like some assistance evaluating your options in the Individual Health Insurance market, please select 'Yes' below and we will help you with this process.</p>

  <div class='form-group'>
    <select  class='form-control' id='sel1' name='wants_ind_health_quote'>
      <option  value='Yes' >Yes</option>
      <option  value='No' >No</option>
    </select>
 <div>{{ $errors->first('wants_ind_health_quote') }}</div>
  </div>

  {{-- <h1 class='py-3'>Status</h1>

  <div class='form-group'>
    <select  class='form-control' id='sel1' name='survey_status'>
      <option  value='In Progress' >In Progress</option>
      <option  value='Complete' >Complete</option>
    </select>
 <div>{{ $errors->first('survey_status') }}</div>
  </div> --}}


  {{-- Submit Button --}}

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
   <div class="col text-right">
      <button type="submit" name="action" value="next_step" class="btn btn-info">Submit</button>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

@endsection

I have the following in my controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //
    $test = Auth::check();
    $userid = Auth::id();
    $user = User::find($userid);


    if ($test == false){
        return redirect('/login');
    }

     else {

            $data = request()->validate ([
                'survey_providers_list' => '',
                'wants_ind_health_quote' => '',
                'comments' => '',

            ]);

            $user->update($data);


            return redirect ('/my-employer-plan');

        }
}
```

I have used dd to verify the $user variable is working properly and the $data variable is pulling in the data.  Both are working properly.  However, the data in my table does not update.  All the columns in the table are spelled correctly.  All I can think of is that I cannot use the update function here for some reason.

Here is the dd($user):

```
App\User {#1368 ▼
  #guarded: []
  #fillable: array:3 [▶]
  #hidden: array:2 [▶]
  #casts: array:1 [▶]
  #connection: "mysql"
  #table: "users"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:13 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "name" => "Wruce Bayne"
    "email" => "bobby@test.com"
    "email_verified_at" => null
    "password" => "$2y$10$cFtf.wT3BE0qbQ68oza8fuKAOYGyTULz1bhzAoL1O3rfHLt3BTI6i"
    "active_plan_id" => null
    "remember_token" => null
    "created_at" => "2020-01-14 22:37:37"
    "updated_at" => "2020-01-14 22:37:37"
    "survey_providers_list" => null
    "wants_ind_health_quote" => null
    "comments" => null
    "survey_status" => null
  ]
  #original: array:13 [▶]
  #changes: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #visible: []
  #rememberTokenName: "remember_token"
}
```

Comment: plz `dd($data)`

Comment: show your user model

Comment: are these three fields fillable? are these three fields required?

Comment: yep all are fillable

Comment: @Alexander so post your `dd($data)`

Comment: can you check dd($request->all()) i think your $request data are empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first in User model add below code

```
protected $fillable = [
    'survey_providers_list' , 
    'wants_ind_health_quote' , 
    'wants_ind_health_quote'
];
```

opssss  Edit Code  : you are filled user model with validation result !!!

```
       $validation = request()->validate ([
            'survey_providers_list' => '',
            'wants_ind_health_quote' => '',
            'comments' => '',
        ]);

        $user->update($request->all());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Post controller
 public function update(Request $request, Post $post)
    {
        if($post->user_id != Auth::id())
        {
            Toastr::error('You are not authorized this post!!!!','Error');
            return redirect()->back();
        }
        $this->validate($request,[
            'title' =>'required',
            // 'zip' => 'zip',
            'image' => 'image',
            'categories' => 'required',
            'tags' => 'required',
            'body' => 'required',
            'live_demo' =>'required'
        ]);


        $zipfile = $request->file('zip');
        $slug = str_slug($request->title);
        if (isset($zipfile))
        {
            $currentDate = Carbon::now()->toDateString();
            $zipname = $slug.'-'.$currentDate.'-'. uniqid() .'.'. $zipfile->getClientOriginalExtension();
            if (!file_exists('storage/uploads/zip'))
            {
                mkdir('storage/uploads/zip',0777,true);
            }
            unlink('storage/uploads/zip/'.$post->zip);
            $zipfile->move('storage/uploads/zip',$zipname);
        }else{
            $zipname = $post->zip;
        }


        $image = $request->file('image');
        $slug = str_slug($request->title);
        if (isset($image))
        {
            $currentDate = Carbon::now()->toDateString();
            $imagename = $slug.'-'.$currentDate.'-'. uniqid() .'.'. $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $image_resize = Image::make($image->getRealPath());
            $image_resize->resize(1600,1066);
            if (!file_exists('storage/uploads/post'))
            {
                mkdir('storage/uploads/post',0777,true);
            }
            unlink('storage/uploads/post/'.$post->image);
            $image_resize->save('storage/uploads/post/'.$imagename);
        }else{
            $imagename = $post->image;
        }

        $post->user_id = Auth::id();
        $post->title = $request->title;
        $post->slug = str_slug($request->title);
        $post->image = $imagename;
        $post->zip = $zipname;
        $post->body = $request->body;
        $post->price = $request->price;
        $post->live_demo = $request->live_demo;
        if(isset($request->status))
        {
            $post->status =true;
        }else
        {
            $post->status = false;
        }
        $post->is_approved = false;
        $post->save();
        $post->categories()->sync($request->categories);
        $post->tags()->sync($request->tags);
        Toastr::success('Post Successfully Updated:)','Success');
        return redirect()->route('user.post.index');
    }

    }
// Route

Route::group(['as'=>'user.','prefix'=>'user','namespace'=>'Author','middleware'=>['auth','user']], function (){
    Route::resource('post','PostController');
    });

// Blade file

@extends('layouts.backend.app')

@section('title')
{{__('Post')}}
@endsection



@push('css')
 <link href="{{asset('backend/plugins/bootstrap-select/css/bootstrap-select.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" />
@endpush
@section('content')
<div class="container-fluid">
           <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="block-header"><a href="{{route('user.post.index')}}"></a></div>
            <!-- Basic Validation -->
            <form action="{{route('user.post.update',$post->id)}}"  method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                @csrf
                                @METHOD('PUT')
            <div class="row clearfix">
                <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="header">
                            <h2>{{__('EDIT POST')}}</h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="body">

                                <div class="form-group form-float">
                                    <div class="form-line">
                                        <input value="{{old('title')}}{{$post->title}}" type="text" class="form-control" name="title" required>
                                        <label class="form-label">{{__('Post Title')}}</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            <div class="form-group form-float">
                                <div class="form-line">
                                    <input value="{{old('price')}}{{$post->price}}" type="text" class="form-control" name="price">
                                    <label class="form-label">{{__('Price')}}</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                                <div class="form-group form-float">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <img src="{{ asset('storage/uploads/post/'.$post->image) }}" width="40px"height="30px" alt=""/>
                                        <input  type="file" class="form-control" name="image" >
                                        <label class="form-label btn btn-primary">{{__(' Your Project ScreenShot')}}</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="checkbox" id="status" class="filled-in" name="status" value="1" {{ $post->status ==  true? 'checked' : ''}}>
                                        <label for="status">{{__('Status')}}</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group form-float">
                                        <div class="form-line">
                                            <input value="{{old('live_demo')}} {{$post->live_demo}}" type="text" class="form-control" name="live_demo" required>
                                            <label class="form-label">{{__('Live Demo')}}</label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input  type="file" class="form-control" name="zip" >
                                        <label class="form-label btn btn-warning">{{__(' Your Project  Upload')}}</label>
                                    </div>


                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="card ">
                        <div class="header bg-blue">
                            <h2 class="">{{__('Categrories & Tags')}}</h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="body">

                                <div class="form-group form-float">
                                    <div class="form-line" {{$errors->has('categories') ? 'fucused error' : '' }}>
                                        <select name="categories[]" id="category" class="form-control show-tick" data-live-search="true" multiple>
                                            <label for="category">{{__('Category Name')}}</label>
                                            @foreach($categories as $category)
                                            <option
                                                @foreach($post->categories as $postCategory)
                                                {{ $postCategory->id  == $category->id? 'selected' : '' }}
                                                @endforeach
                                             value="{{$category->id}}">{{$category->name}}</option>
                                            @endforeach
                                        </select>

                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group form-float">
                                    <div class="form-line" {{$errors->has('tags') ? 'fucused error' : '' }}>
                                        <select name="tags[]" id="tag" class="form-control show-tick" data-live-search="true" multiple>
                                            <label for="tag">{{__('Tag Name')}}</label>
                                            @foreach($tags as $tag)
                                            <option 
                                                @foreach($post->tags as $postTag)
                                                {{$postTag->id == $tag->id? 'selected' : ''}}
                                                @endforeach
                                             value="{{$tag->id}}">{{$tag->name}}</option>
                                            @endforeach
                                        </select>

                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <a class="btn btn-danger" href="{{route('user.post.index')}}">{{__('BACK')}}</a>
                                <button class="btn btn-primary waves-effect" type="submit">{{__('SUBMIT')}}</button>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row clearfix">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="header">
                            <h2>{{__('Documanation')}}</h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="body">
                              <textarea id="tinymce" name="body">
                               {{old('body')}} {!! $post->body!!}
                            </textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
@endsection

@push('js')
<script src="{{asset('backend/plugins/bootstrap-select/js/bootstrap-select.js')}}"></script>
  <script src="{{ asset('backend/plugins/tinymce/tinymce.js') }}"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            //TinyMCE
            tinymce.init({
                selector: "textarea#tinymce",
                theme: "modern",
                height: 300,
                plugins: [
                    'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak',
                    'searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen',
                    'insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality',
                    'emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern imagetools'
                ],
                toolbar1: 'insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image',
                toolbar2: 'print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons',
                image_advtab: true
            });
            tinymce.suffix = ".min";
            tinyMCE.baseURL = '{{ asset('backend/plugins/tinymce') }}';
        });
    </script>
@endpush
```